# php convert timestamp to readable date

Tags: php

I am looking to convert timestamp dates into readable formats, preferably YYYY-MM-DD, my current dates are in the following format:

1398898800000

Any assistance appreciated.

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mSecUnix / 1000)`

Answer (score 3):

The times look like they're coming from javascript, so you need to divide by 1000. So:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', 1398898800000 / 1000);
```

check out the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.